# how can assign inpustream file to the json?

Tags: java, json, inputstream

```
DataInputStream rd = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
```

Upper code is for server. server get a inpustream and i want this stream to be assigned to the JsonObject.
how can i assign this "rd" to the "json"?

Comment: Where does your `JsonObject` come from, Gson?

Comment: nop, it's from restfb(for the facebook api using in java)

Comment: Convert the stream to String and String -> object , from object using GSON you can easily convert json if it helps you i can post the code

Comment: @Ranjith - can you post the code ?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the input stream to string

```
    public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
       if (is != null) {
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        try {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
            int n;
            while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.getStackTraceString(e);
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        return writer.toString();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Stream to object using pojo class for eg:

```
public class PageInfo { 
private String pageName;
private String pageContent;


public String getPageName() {
    return pageName;
}

public void setPageName(String pageName) {
    this.pageName = pageName;
}

public String getColorCode() {
    return colorCode;
}

public void setColorCode(String colorCode) {
    this.colorCode = colorCode;
}
```

}

Mapper Class to Convert String to Object

```
 public Vector<PageInfo> getPageInfo(Cursor cursor) {
    Vector<PageInfo> pageInfo = new Vector<PageInfo>();
    // Column Index
    int pageContent;


    if (cursor != null) {

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                PageInfo info  = new PageInfo();

                pageContent = cursor.getColumnIndex(TablePageInfo.PAGE_CONTENT);
                colorCode = cursor.getColumnIndex(TablePageInfo.COLOR_CODE);
                bookMark = cursor.getColumnIndex(TablePageInfo.BOOK_MARK);

                info.setPageContent(cursor.getString(pageContent));


                pageInfo.add(info);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return pageInfo;
}
```

Add GSON Jar then write the below code it will get any object and will return a perfect JSON

```
package common;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

//Generics is used so any class type can be passed
public class GsonSerializer<T> {

public T Deserialize(String json, Class classOfT) {

Gson gn = new GsonBuilder().create();

return (T) gn.fromJson(json, classOfT);

}

public String Serialize(T object) {

Gson gn = new GsonBuilder().create();

return gn.toJson(object);

}

}
```

For more detail you can refer my blog

http://lifeasanandroiddeveloper.blogspot.kr/2011/11/how-to-serialize-and-desearilize-json.html

Answer (score 0):

Convert to `String` and then to the `JSONObject`.

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(request.getInputStream(), writer, encoding);
String theString = writer.toString();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(theString);
```

For details on `IOUtils` have a look [here](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html).

To get the jar containing the `IOUtils` class have a look [here](http://commons.apache.org/io/download_io.cgi)

Comment: what is "IOUtils"? i cannot import that